# How can I access a MailItem after it has been sent?

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

From my WPF app I create and display a `MailItem` like following:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

Application outlook = new Application();
NameSpace ns = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");
MailItem mailItem = outlook.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
mailItem.Display(false);
string lastEntryId = mailItem.EntryID; // remember EntryId
```

The user can now compose and send the mail.

After the user did send the mail he confirms the sending in my app. My app then should save the mail in file system. My approach was to "remember" the `MailItem.EntryID` to use it after sending.

```
// ... lastEntryId is null therefore this code doesn't work
MailItem mailItem = ns.GetItemFromID(lastEntryId);
string fileName = GetValidFileName(item.Subject) + ".msg";
string file = Path.Combine(GetSaveDirectory(), fileName);
item.SaveAs(file);
```

But `lastEntryId` is `null` before sending therefore I cannot use it.

Question is: how can I access the MailItem after it has been sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you had the entry id before the message was sent, it would change when the message is sent and moved to the Sent Items folder. It stays the same only under the PST store.

`Items.ItemAdd` event on the Sent Items folder is the earliest you can access the sent message.

You can also use `Application.ItemSend` event if you don't care whether the message is in the sent state or not.

Comment: How do I identify the sent item when receiving the event? Is it possible to set a custom id or something?

Comment: I think UserProperties can be used to identify the MailItem afterwards.

Comment: Adding a user property will force the message to be sent in the TNEF format (the infamous winmail.dat attachment). Add the same property using MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty. You can see the DASL property name (to be used when calling SetProperty) in OutlookSpy - select a message with the user property already added, click IMessage button on the OutlookSpy ribbon, select the property, see the DASL edit box.